# Extracting bytes from a register

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

I'm measuring with a Sensor Temperature, Pressure and Humidity. For those three values the sensor has the following Register as you can see in the Picture:

[image: Sensor Memory map]
All in all we have 8 Byte. The 8 byte are sended via Bluetooth smart to my android phone where I wanna extract the data of the packages to get the values for pressure, temperature and humidity. But I'm only able to send packages of size 4 byte. Because of this, the 8 Byte are splitted in two packages of 4 byte.
First package contains adresses 0xF7,0xF8,0xF9,0xFA
Second package contains adresses 0xFB,0xFC,0xFD,0xFE

For receiving the data packages I use the Android BluetoothGattCharacteristic in Java.

The Format of the packages I receive is HEX.

For extracting the data I have this code until now:

```
 public static void extractData_Sensor1(BluetoothGattCharacteristic package1, BluetoothGattCharacteristic package2){

            byte[] one = package1.getValue();
            byte[] two = package2.getValue();
            byte[] Data_Sensor_1 = new byte[one.length + two.length];
            System.arraycopy(one,0,Data_Sensor_1,0         ,one.length);
            System.arraycopy(two,0,Data_Sensor_1,one.length,two.length);

        }
```

So I receive the two packets and copy them in one byte array. My Problem is that I don't know, how to extract the values for pressure, temperature and humidity.
Maybe already this is the wrong way, so please help me out!

Thanks in Advance!